# Default RequestContext in Django

Tags: python, django, templates, httprequest, django-context

I have such a function(view)

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and want to write just

```
return render_to_response('index.html')
```

Also I want to pass additional variables to view

```
return render_to_response('cart.html', {'key': value})
```

The main reason I need RequestContext is that I have context processor function that sets additional variables for me. How can I achieve that or is there different approach for doing such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `render` shortcut:

```
return render(request, 'cart.html', {'key': value})
```

You always need to pass the request, though: that's why it's called a RequestContext.

Comment: Indeed, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render